# Have core-toolbar Stay at the Top of the Page

Tags: javascript, css, html, polymer

I'm trying to get a polymer `<core-toolbar>` to stay at the top of the page when the user scrolls the page. How can I do this with HTML/JavaScript/CSS?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Polymer 0.5 or older? The latest polymer versions use paper components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the core-scroll-header-panel.  This wraps around your core-toolbar and gives you various options that will allow you to style it how you want, wither it should scroll away or stay fixed at the top.  You will want to check out the help pages to get all the attributes available. [core-scroll-header-panel](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-scroll-header-panel.html)

The option you are looking for will look something like:

```
<core-scroll-header-panel fixed>
 <core-toolbar>Header</core-toolbar>
  <div>Content goes here...</div>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```